# Django each model must have a date_created and date_modified field

Tags: python, mysql, django

Is there a way to have a `date_created` and `date_modified` fields for each and every model in models.py?

I would like to have these two fields for each table being created so that I will be able to know when a row is created or updated.

But I don't want to have them shown in my models.py specifically for each model.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What about using a superclass?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks. I'm new to OOP. Yeah! I got it. Thanks again.

Comment: Make an abstract class model (containing these two fields). Other models should inherit this abstract model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could for example define an *abstract* supermodel. Like:

```
class AppModel(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Here we use `auto_now_add=True` and `auto_now`, these parameters will even ensure that the `date_created` is automatically set to the timestamp when the object was created, and `date_modified` will automatically get updated when you update the object in the database.

Then you can subclass it. For example for a model called `SomeModel`:

```
class SomeModel(AppModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Making the model `abstract = True` is rather important (well it can still work without making it abstract, but it will make the database quite messy and less efficient). By specifying this is abstract, it will add the two columns to *every* model that inherits from this model. In case you do not make it abstract, Django will construct a new table, but typically this will make queries less efficient.

Since you here add columns to (potentially a large amount of) models, this will require a migration that will add the columns to the database level. In case there is already data stored in the application, you will need to find a way to resolve the columns for rows that already exist (for example set it to `NOW()`, or to the beginning of times).

Comment: I also have a custom User model `User(AbstractUser)`. How can I inherit from abstract model here?

Comment: @whitehathackersree: yes, Python supports multiple inheritance, so you can write `User(AppModel, AbstractUser)`.

Comment: And lets say the `AbstractUser` here also consists of the same field names. Then what happens if these field datatypes are same as `AppModel` and what if the datatypes are different but have same names?

Comment: @whitehathackersree: In Python the order is determined by the MRO. The MRO here is `User -> AppModel -> AbstractUser -> ...`, so the first in that MRO counts (so here it will take the fields of `AppModel` as the "real" columns, and ignore the ones from `AbstractUser` in case of a clash.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could help me with this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51177983/is-it-good-to-use-json-field-to-store-user-defined-fields